# Problems with math.h

Tags: c++, math

I'm writing a program that is using the functions `sin()` and `cos()` from the `math.h` library.  However, I noticed I was getting funky results.  After searching around and checking my math multiple times, I decided to do a simple check with this:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "sin(45.0) = " << sin(45) << endl;
    cout << "cos(45.0) = " << cos(45) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this output:

```
 sin(45) = 0.850904
 cos(45) = 0.525322
```

These should be equal right?  Is there something special about the `math.h` library?  Am I doing something wrong?

Here are the equations in WolframAlpha:

[sin(45)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2845%29)

[cos(45)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%2845%29)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`cmath`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) in C++, rather than the old C header.

[`std::sin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) and [`std::cos()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cos) both take a floating point value representing an angle in [radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

[The GCC version of this file includes a handy constant for π](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html), (which does not exist in the C++ standard but) which will make it easier for you to convert degrees to radian:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

double degrees_to_radian(double deg)
{
    return deg * M_PI / 180.0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sin(45.0) = " << std::sin(degrees_to_radian(45)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cos(45.0) = " << std::cos(degrees_to_radian(45)) << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/mWcu6)

Answer (score 9):

`sin` and `cos` expect input in radians not degrees.
try this:
`sin(degrees * pi / 180)`

Answer (score 6):

Trigonometric functions use [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees.

Answer (score 3):

`sin()` and `cos()` treat your parameter as Radians not Degrees.